# jdbc PreparedStatement не выполняеться

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

PreparedStatement не выполняется конкретно этот запрос а все остальные работают,
проходил код дебагером но даже исключения нет как и значений в таблице. Выполнял этот запрос в студии и все работало но не через jdbc.

```
SQL = insert into main.tokens(token, user_id) values(?,(select id from users where login = ? and password = ?));
             1 = "node01ai8r5ecckvnn13btntwu0jool0"
             2 = "admin"
             3 = "admin"

public boolean  authentication(String login, String password, String sessionid)  {
    try {
        this.auth.setString(1,sessionid);
        this.auth.setString(2,login);
        this.auth.setString(3, password);
        return this.auth.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Приведите лучше код, в котором вы пытаетесь его выполнить, это даст больше шансов на ответ.

Comment: может просто нет `commit` после транзакции

Comment: попробовал, не помогло